# Causal Inference Short Time Series

Tags: time-series, causality, small-sample, difference-in-difference, intervention-analysis

I am trying to analyse causal inference associated with an intervenion using either Difference-in-Differences or Interrupted Time Series Analysis. I have a discrete time series consisting of data covering a four year period, which could either be aggregated by month [allowing for 24 observations in both the pre- and post-intervention periods] or quarterly [8 observations in each period]. Ideally, I assume that aggregation by month would be preferable....however there is a distinct possibility that there will be a large number of zero value observations, which I assume would make the use of regression techniques more complex.

Were aggregation to be undertaken by quarter there would likely be less zeros, but much potentially insufficient observations for ITS [as the preferred method]. Does anyone know of reliable models for use in regards to data with either a small number of observations or data with large numbers of zero values?

Any help hugely appreciated.....

Comment: Just to help yourself here: as you have "so little data" it would be relevant to do a small simulation study to see what *can* be estimated. If the simulation study, where we know the true ATE, is unable to pick up the correct answer then expecting to achieve this using real data is unreasonable.